# My class cannot be cast to class to class java.lang.Comparable

Tags: comparator, java

First of all, I know that someone has already posted this question, but their solution can't solve my problem, unfortunately.

Let me explain, I have a Book class (Libro) and a concrete class that extends the abstract class (LibroConcreto).
Also, I have a Catalog class characterized by a container of Books (type T).
What I should do is assign a book to the container and in other methods return a copy of this book container sorted by title or by year (which are attributes of the book class), depending on the user's choice. To do this, I use a TreeSet and two classes that implement the Comparator class.

However, in the main at the time of assigning the Book to the attribute list of the catalog, the following exception is thrown at run time:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class trac1settembre2019.libro.LibroConcreto cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (trac1settembre2019.libro.LibroConcreto is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base / java.util.TreeMap.compare (TreeMap.java:1291)
    at java.base / java.util.TreeMap.put (TreeMap.java:536)
    at java.base / java.util.TreeSet.add (TreeSet.java:255)
    at trac1september2019.catalogue.Catalogue.addbook (Catalog.java:28)
    at trac1settembre2019.test.TestProgramma.main (TestProgramma.java:42)
```

Below is my code:

```
package traccia1settembre2019.catalogo;
    
import java.util.Comparator;
    
import traccia1settembre2019.libro.Libro;
    
public class LibriByAnno implements Comparator <Libro>{
    public int compare (Libro obj1, Libro obj2) {
        return obj1.getAnnoPubblicazione()-obj2.getAnnoPubblicazione();
    }
}
```

```
package traccia1settembre2019.catalogo;

import java.util.Comparator;
import traccia1settembre2019.libro.Libro;
    
public class LibriByTitolo implements Comparator <Libro>{
    public int compare (Libro obj1, Libro obj2) {
        return obj1.getTitolo().compareToIgnoreCase(obj2.getTitolo());
    }
}
```

```
package traccia1settembre2019.test;
    
import traccia1settembre2019.catalogo.Catalogo;
import traccia1settembre2019.libro.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
    
public class TestProgramma {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numeroLibri;
        Catalogo<LibroConcreto> c1=new Catalogo ();
        int maxNumLibri=Catalogo.getMaxLibri();
        LibroConcreto l;        
        Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);
        String stringa;
        int anno;
        int numeroCopie;
        int maxCopie=Libro.getMaxCopie();
        
        do {
            System.out.println ("Quanti libri vuoi inserire?");
            numeroLibri=in.nextInt();
        } while (numeroLibri>maxNumLibri);
        
        stringa=in.nextLine();
            
        for (int i=0; i<numeroLibri; i++) {
            System.out.println ("Inserire il titolo: ");
            stringa=in.nextLine();
            System.out.println ("Inserire l'anno di pubblicazione");
            anno=in.nextInt();
            
            do {
                System.out.println ("Inserire il numero di copie disponibili, deve essere un numero minore di "+maxCopie);
                numeroCopie=in.nextInt();
            } while (numeroCopie>maxCopie);
            
            l=new LibroConcreto (stringa, anno, numeroCopie);
            
            c1.aggiungiLibro(l);
        }
        
        Set <LibroConcreto> c1OrdinatoByAnno=c1.leggiLibriByAnno();
        
        for (Libro l2: c1OrdinatoByAnno) {
            System.out.println (l2);
        }
        
        Set <LibroConcreto> c1OrdinatoByTitolo=c1.leggiLibriByAnno();
        
        for (Libro l3: c1OrdinatoByTitolo) {
            System.out.println (l3);
        }
    }   
}
```

```
package traccia1settembre2019.catalogo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import traccia1settembre2019.libro.Libro;

public class Catalogo <T extends Libro>{
    private Set <T > libri;
    private int codice;
    private int numLibri;
    private static int numeroCataloghi;
    private static final int MAX_LIBRI=300;

    public Catalogo () {
        libri=new TreeSet <> ();
        numeroCataloghi++;
        codice=numeroCataloghi;
        numLibri=0;
    }
    
    public boolean aggiungiLibro (T obj) {
        if (numLibri<MAX_LIBRI) {
            libri.add(obj);
            numLibri++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public Set<T> leggiLibriByAnno () {
        Set <T> copia=new TreeSet <>(new LibriByAnno());
        copia.addAll(libri);
        return copia;
    }
    
    public Set<T> leggiLibriByTitolo () {
        Set <T> copia=new TreeSet <>(new LibriByTitolo());
        copia.addAll(libri);
        return copia;
    }
    
    public int numLibriCatalogabili () {
        return MAX_LIBRI-numLibri;
    }
    
    public String libroAntico () {
        List <Libro> lista=new ArrayList <> ();
        lista.addAll(libri);
        Libro l=Collections.min (lista, new LibriByAnno());
        return l.getTitolo();
    }
    
    public void eliminazioneLibri () {
         this.libri.clear();
    }
    
    public int hashCode () {
        final int prime=31;
        int result=1;
        result=prime*result+codice;
        return result;
    }
    
    public boolean equals (Object obj) {
        if (obj==this)
            return true;
        if (obj==null) 
            return false;
        if (getClass()!=obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Catalogo <T> other=(Catalogo<T>)obj;
        if (other.getCodice()==codice)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int getCodice() {
        return codice;
    }
    
    public String toString () {
        return "Catalogo: [codice="+codice+", numero di libri:"+numLibri+", libri="+libri+"]";
    }

    public static int getMaxLibri() {
        return MAX_LIBRI;
    }
}
```

```
package traccia1settembre2019.libro;

public abstract class Libro {
    private String titolo;
    private int annoPubblicazione;
    private int numCopieDisponibili;
    private static final int MAX_COPIE_DISPONIBILI=5;
    
    public Libro (String titolo, int anno, int numCopie) {
        this.titolo=titolo;
        this.annoPubblicazione=anno;
        this.numCopieDisponibili=numCopie;
    }

    public String getTitolo() {
        return titolo;
    }
    
    public int getAnnoPubblicazione() {
        return annoPubblicazione;
    }
    
    public int getNumCopieDisponibili() {
        return numCopieDisponibili;
    }
    
    public String toString () {
        return "Libro: [ titolo="+titolo+", anno di pubblicazione="+annoPubblicazione+", numero di copie disponibili="+numCopieDisponibili;
    }
    
    public static int getMaxCopie () {
        return MAX_COPIE_DISPONIBILI;
    }
    
}
```

```
package traccia1settembre2019.libro;
    
public class LibroConcreto extends Libro {
    
    public LibroConcreto(String titolo, int anno, int numCopie) {
        super(titolo, anno, numCopie);
    }
    
    public String toString () {
        return super.toString()+"]";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Should be `implements Comparable` I'd encourage you to use `@Override` annotations too

Comment: Please edit your question to a readable one, you can separate error and code also you can do proper indentation for this code you provided in the question.

Comment: Compar*able* and Compar*ator* are not the same thing.

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa sorry, i improved my post.

Comment: Where is the definition of Libro class?

Comment: To use a `TreeSet` or a `TreeMap` one of two conditions must be true: either 1. all elements added to it must implement the appropriate `Comparable` interface **or** 2. you pass in an appropriate `Comparator` when you construct the set/map. The error message shows that neither of the two conditions are met, instead you seem to implement `Comparator` object but not actually pass them in when you construct the `TreeSet`.

Comment: I edited the post and added: @Bohemian
the Abstract book class and the Concrete book class.

Comment: @LorenzoBucci: you create a `TreeSet` "correctly" 2 times and without a comparator once. But note that your code won't do what you want, even if you get it to work, since comparing object as "equal" in the comparator means only one of them will end up in the set. In other words: when you try to get the set sorted by publishing year, you'll end up with at most 1 book per year, all others will be discarded.

Comment: How would you suggest I create two copies of sorted TreeSets? sorted one by year and one by title. If you could give me an example, I would be grateful.  @JoachimSauer

Comment: @LorenzoBucci: similar to what you already do, but make sure to *never* return `0` for any two objects that you don't want to treat as identical. In other words: have some secondary comparison for objects that would otherwise compare as equal.

Comment: I didn't understand, should I delete the classes that implement the Comparator interface, that is LibriByAnno and LibriByTitolo?
and if i had to use the compareTo method how do i sort by both year and title? If you could indicate the changes to be made to the code, I would be grateful. @g00se

Comment: I would make your 'default' sort the target of the `Comparable` implementation *if* you think they should sort by default. If you're happy to have them only sort when you want, then, as someone has already said, you can pass a `Comparator` to a `TreeSet` to have them sorted in that collection by whatever field(s) you want

Comment: I made the Libro class implement the Comparable interface, and the program finally starts running. However, I cannot solve the problem you already mentioned to me. In fact, the catalog does not add more than one book. Could you please tell me exactly which piece of code to modify and what to write? 
if you could show me a concrete example in code. sorry but I'm a beginner. 

@JoachimSauer